# Error while running dotnet restore Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props not found

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

When we run dotnet restore

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\s\My.Project.sln --configfile C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\Nuget\tempNuGet_3682.config --verbosity Detailed
```

> "C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\s\My.Project.sln"
>   (Restore target) (1) ->
>          "C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\s\My.Project\My.Project.sfproj" (_IsProjectRestoreSupported target) (2) ->
>          (ValidateMSBuildFiles target) -> 
>            C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\s\My.Project\My.Project.sfproj(49,5):
>   error : Unable to find the
>   '..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props'
>   file. Please restore the 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild'
>   Nuget package.

But when I restore with nuget restore i am able to restore

```
C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\_tool\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe restore C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\s\My.Project.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile C:\agent\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.119.1\vstswrk\58\Nuget\tempNuGet_3675.config
```

Comment: Is it .core project?

Comment: yes it is .net core project service fabric

Answer (score 2):

The service fabric project itself (that has all the config files and does the packaging of services) uses `packages.config` to gets the build tools. `dotnet restore` doesn't support `packages.config`, hence you must use `nuget restore`.

The Service Fabric team do have plans to move the `sfproj` to an SDK-style project, but at the time of writing, there are some issues in Visual Studio with SDK style projects where the SDK comes from a NuGet package that need to be resolved to avoid giving customers a poor VS experience. Once that becomes available and you migrate your `sfproj` to sdk style, then `dotnet restore` should work, but until then you need to use `nuget restore` in your CI pipelines.